# Time and sample rate for QAM

Tags: digital-communications

I am trying to understand how to get time as I already have sample rate. I want to draw a graph of sample rate vs time. I have information such as carrier frequency, channel bandwidth. Can that be used to get time.

So far, I have understood this: [Samples per symbol and number of symbols for QAM](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66516/samples-per-symbol-and-number-of-symbols-for-qam)

In order to get the time, I would need to do this:

T = 1/Samples per symbol

Would this be correct.

Comment: "I want to draw a graph of sample rate vs time" this is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry, I new to this field and I am learning. The previous suggestion in the above link is to draw a sample rate vs time graph and I am trying to do that. Thank you

Comment: Rate of transmissions is usually fixed for a given configuration and it does not vary with time. That is why I asked to clarify.

Comment: I will go back to the other link and clarify with engineer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have a bandwidth of B. The sampling rate $F_s$ which is related to B using the relation $F_s > 2B$. Now the sample time is $\frac{1}{F_s}$. So if you have N samples  then total time is $\frac{N}{F_s}$

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help